# disappearing View/Edit buttons at the top-right corner of a Chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I remember there used to be a View/Edit toggle button on the top-right corner of a a Chart in Google Sheets. The View mode would allow me to hover over a datapoint, e.g. in a bubble chart, and get the associated values for it.

I just checked this morning on a fresh spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14IpjIjHrP3PytDsaZu56_54hxkSILq1fTyTbOsCu5s8/edit?usp=sharing

And I don't see the Edit/View options anymore. How can I hover over the bubbles in the chart and see their associated values?[image]

EDIT: I tried this both on Chrome and Firefox, same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There's no longer an Edit/View button.

There is a View mode which shows values when you hover. This is the mode I'm currently getting when I click on your link, since you haven't given editing privileges to the public. You can also view it by publishing it to the web and using the generated link. Go to **File** -> **Publish to the web..** Make sure only the appropriate people, if any, are given access, and to the required sheets only.

There's also an **advanced edit..** mode, which you get by right clicking on the chart or clicking that tiny arrow at the top-right corner of the chart. This mode also shows values when you hover.
[image: Advanced edit.. menu]

**Edit 28th May 2017**:
The View/Edit button is once again available, this time on the right side.
[image: View/Edit button]

Comment: You can see it when you publish it, and view it with the generated link. To publish, go to File -> Publish to the web... I'll add this to the answer

Comment: Wow, I was also looking for this and with the lack of docs on Google's part I thought I had gone mad but I could swear that this option used to be there. Serves me right for thinking that Google wouldn't remove features from a product! Apparently charts that were in view mode before this "improvment" are stuck in view mode as well.

Comment: Yes... one of the very few times I've seen Google's updates confusing people more than making things easier.

Comment: Guys, the View/Edit button is back xD